# How to combine results from Wilcoxon Rank Sum Test for multiple imputed data sets from proc MI in SAS

Tags: wilcoxon-mann-whitney-test, multiple-imputation, combining-p-values

Endpoint information:

We have seizure count collected for every day and therefore there will be some missing for some days.

1. We got average seizure frequency per 28-day, for an interval. That is, (seizure acount for a interval)/ (days with available seizure count during the interval)*28. For example, baseline period (28 days) DB period (99 days).
2. Then the endpoint is percent change from baseline in seizure frequency. (per 28-day seizure frequency during DB - per 28-day seizure frequency during baseline)/(per 28-days seizure frequency during baseline) 100% .

We will impute seizure count for each day if it is missing. So we will have m (say 10) imputed seizure count data sets.

Q1. After imputation, we plan calculaton the endpoint for each imputed data, is this correct? Can we stack all the 10 data sets  and then calculate the endpoint?
Q2. Assume we calculate the endpoint for each imputed data. Then do Wilcoxon Rank Sum test. We will have 10 p-values and 10 corresponding 'z' values, etc. How should we combine them together to get one pooled p-value? How should we make inferences based on the 10 imputed data sets?

Thanks.

Janet

Answer (score 0):

The only built-in way to combine multiply imputed analyses in SAS is to use [`PROC MIANALYZE`](https://documentation.sas.com/doc/en/statug/15.2/statug_mianalyze_toc.htm), which implements Rubin's rules. These are not that complicated, I'll reproduce them below, but the big assumption is that your statistic of interest follows a normal distribution. The input for Rubin's rules requires some way to obtain the between-imputation variance (calculated from the statistic of each imputation, usually a mean) and compare it to the within-imputation variance (usually the standard error of the mean).

The Wilcoxon rank sum test is not calculated from such statistics and only really results in a *P*-value instead. The $W$ statistic may be asymptotically normal but the concept of a standard error does not really exist in a non-parametric setting. There have been proposals for imputation combination rules based on just *P*-values, one such is the median *P* rule where you just take the median of all imputed *P*-values, but I would definitely consider this an area of active research.

Your analysis of the imputed datasets should indeed be on each separate imputation by the way (e.g. use a `by _IMPUTATION_` statement in your analysis SAS PROC). Only in the final step are the statistics of interest from each imputation combined again.

Rubin's rules in case you are unfamiliar with them: consider $m$ imputed datasets where in each you calculate the statistic of interest $\hat Q$ (again, usually a mean or model parameter) along with its variance $\hat W$ (usually the standard error of the mean). The combined point estimate is just the mean of the imputed statistics $\bar Q=\frac{1}{m}\sum_{i=1}^{m}\hat Q_i$. The within-imputation variance is similarly the mean $\bar W=\frac{1}{m}\sum_{i=1}^{m}\hat W_i$. The between-imputation variance $B$ is the variance of the $\hat Q_i$ or $B=\frac{1}{m-1}\sum_{i=1}^{m}(\hat Q_i-\bar Q)^2$. The total imputation variance is $T=\bar W+(1+\frac{1}{m})B$. Inference on $\bar Q$ can be drawn from the statistic $\frac{Q-\bar Q}{\sqrt{T}}$ which follows a $t$ distribution with degrees of freedom $v_m=(m-1)\left(1+\frac{\bar W}{(1+m^{-1})B}\right)^2$.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your clear explanation. So, firstly, I know I should not consider do analysis on pooled imputed data sets but seperately. Secondly, I have read some about Rubin's rule these days. But your summary is so clear that I understand well.

Comment: Third, some 'exact' method is a 'research' till this moment.  But for Rubin's rule, from Wilcoxon Rank Sum Test output, which variable should I put into proc MIanalysis, 'z', S, or sumofscore, or sumofscore - expectofSum, not think over yet, Any suggestion? Thanks again

Comment: I'm not sure what most of these variables are exactly. The Z score is the one that's going to be normally distributed, but as I mentioned above you won't have a variance (that I know of) for this quantity to apply Rubin's rules to.